# R get every column with NA

Tags: r

I need a function in R which is doing the following.
I have a matrix with some data

```
mydata <- data.frame (matrix(c(1,2,3,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2), 3,3))

mydata
  X1 X2 X3
1  1 NA NA
2  2  2 NA
3  3  3  2
```

No I want to check every column of this matrix if there is any NA in a column and create a vector which stores 0 if there is a NA in a column or 1 if there is no NA in the column.

So check column X1: if NA is in this column write 0 to the vector, if not write 1 to the vector. Then check the next column and so on.

After checking mydata the vector should look like this

```
(1 0 0)
```

with

```
colnames(mydata)[colSums(is.na(mydata)) > 0]
```

I get the column names which have NA. But how can I use this function to create the vector?

Comment: `sapply(mydata, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))`

Comment: `ifelse(colSums(is.na(mydata)) == 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: Amazing!! this is exactly doing what I need

Comment: Another method: `as.integer(unlist(vapply(mydata, anyNA, logical(1))))`.

Answer (score 0):

We can coerce the logical vector from `colSums` on the logical `matrix` to binary with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(!colSums(is.na(mydata)))
#[1] 1 0 0
```